# how foursquare determine a user location?

Tags: foursquare

I just use foursquare first time, looks it find my location and shows on the map very correct. I am using desktop at home, just curious, how does it know my address? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It uses HTML5's [Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) to determine a user's location

Answer (score 0):

It uses the GPS from your phone and updates your position on that.

For an exact businesses you are at, you "Check-In" to a business through the app.

Comment: Thanks. But I am using cable internet, not phone. maybe it determines by IP?