# Google Play or HTML5 geolocation

Tags: android, html, geolocation, google-play, foursquare

I am currently an app which fetches user location at regular interval. I am using **google play services api** for that. It works fine. But sometimes it **fails to get location** even if it connects to playstore. I found none these issues with foursqaure app. I came to know that they are using **HTML5 geolocation api** from stackoverflow itself.

[how foursquare determine a user location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899694/how-foursquare-determine-a-user-location)

**How can i implement this Geolocation api in my app?
What are the benefits and problems of using this api?**

Answer (score 0):

That's a very very broad question.

The easiest solution is implement what you need to be done in javascript, for example getting a position:

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    });
```

Now, where to run this code, a straightforward solution is just running it inside a webview.

Other alternatives for running Javascript on android are [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) or [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino).

I really can't help you any further, considering you never tell us what you want to do with the geolocation.

Comment: Am making a location based alarm. So i need to continuosly fetch location and compare it with destination coordinates.
the actual problem is if there occurs any network problem it cant fetch location anymore... and it won't alarm when it reaches the destination...

Comment: I'm curious as to why google play's location service is failing, have you come to a conclusion about that? Some common issues are power requirements being too low for the sensor to get a signal.

Comment: if phone goes out of coverage area, the play will not fetch location even after getting back into network...